# What is this pdf software

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, latex

i am not sure if this is the right website to ask, but in one presentation, the lecturer used this software

[image]

that i thought was quite neat. If anyone knows it, i would appreciate any comment :)!

Y

Comment: Why didn't you ask the lecturer?

Comment: it was a recording :)

Comment: As [we don't do "software identification"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/818/185) here: What do you need? Which features? What OS should it run on? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid software?

Comment: Hey Izzy, i think Sebastian answered the question. However, if you have any recommendation of something, i would appreciate it. What i am looking for is a pdf viewer when presenting with beamer  that allows me to add blank pages and write on them. another nice feature would be to use the mouse as a laser pointer. Basically a flexible pdf viewer! I don't mind paying an extra buck for something that allows me to be flexible when teaching and presenting :)!

Y

Comment: @YousefKaddoura Can you reformulate the question (or create a new one) that's on-topic for the site, asking for your desired PDF viewer with all features you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it looked like a Linux app, and it seems it is:

[Xournal++](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/xournalpp-handwritten-notes-app-linux)